# UnboundLocalError when using module inside a function?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

When importing from the `string` module, to use with a parsing function.

```
from string import punctuation


def parsing_func(data):
    if not any(i==v for i in data for v in punctuation.replace('_', '')):
        print data
```

Using `string`'s `punctuation` like in this function above, everything works fine.

I then wanted to check data against a couple of less punctuation marks. So I
changed `parsing_func` to this:

```
def parsing_func(data):
    punctuation = punctuation.replace('_', '')
    punctuation = punctuation.replace('()', '')
    if not any(i==v for i in data for v in punctuation):
        print data
```

but this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 58, in <module>
    parsing_func(data)
  File "ex.py", line 8, in parsing_func
    punctuation = punctuation.replace('_', '')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'punctuation' referenced before assignment
```

So, I make a test function to check `punctuation`:

```
def test_func1():
    print type(punctuation), punctuation

>>> <type 'str'> !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Which prints out fine, no errors, and shows `type str`.  Finally, I try to put together `print` and the string operation one after another.

```
def test_func2():
    print type(punctuation), punctuation
    punctuation = punctuation.replace('_', '')
```

but now the `print` statement returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    test_func2()
  File "parser.py", line 5, in test_func2
    print type(punctuation), punctuation
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'punctuation' referenced before assignment
```

Is this a `namespace` error and why would `test_func2` return the error when going to print instead of on the string operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to `punctuation` inside your function, so Python treats it as a local variable: therefore it doesn't use the global name at all. Use a different name for the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have both a local `punctuation` and a global `punctuation` in your second function. You can either rename it:

```
def parsing_func(data):
    punct = punctuation.replace('_', '')
    punct = punctuation.replace('()', '')

    if not any(i == v for i in data for v in punct):
        print data
```

Or make `punctuation` explicitly a global:

```
def parsing_func(data):
    global punctuation

    punctuation = punctuation.replace('_', '')
    punctuation = punctuation.replace('()', '')

    if not any(i==v for i in data for v in punctuation):
        print data
```

Do note that this modifies `punctuation` globally, so I wouldn't do this.

You can also do this with sets:

```
def has_punctuation(data):
    punct = set(punctuation) - set('_()')

    return punct & set(data)  # Intersection of the two sets
```

Comment: Your last example assumes `data` doesn't need duplicates or order.

Comment: @Lattyware: It looked like OP's code just checked to see if the string contained any punctuation, so I don't think that needs any order.

Comment: That's a good point, I wasn't thinking about it as a replacement for the test.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are trying to assign to a global name - `punctuation`, which Python doesn't allow, so instead, it creates a local variable `punctuation`. At this point, it then tries to look up `punctuation` on the right hand side, and gets the local variable, which doesn't exist yet.

To solve this, you could use `global` to modify the global variable (which is a bad idea, and probably not what you want), or simply assign it to a local name.

```
def parsing_func(data):
    less_punctuation = punctuation.replace('_', '')
    less_punctuation = less_punctuation.replace('()', '')
    if not any(i in less_punctuation for i in data):
        print data
```

It's also worth noting my use of `in` to check for membership - it is both more readable and faster. In general, membership tests are faster on sets, and by using sets, we can also remove the values in a more readable way:

```
def parsing_func(data):
    less_punctuation = set(punctuation) - set("_()")
    if not any(i in less_punctuation for i in data):
        print data
```